# EBUSY error when invoking NuGet.exe from Gulp

Tags: .net, gulp, nuget

I'm using Gulp to build a large .NET solution which uses lots of NuGet packages. This has been working well for the past six months using [gulp-nuget-restore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nuget-restore) to fetch the packages before compiling.

However we recently acquired an internal NuGet server, and when I amended the build script to use this it started failing to find `System.Core` (even though all the other packages from nuget.org still worked). I suspect that the culprit is an obsolete version of nuget.exe which is bundled with the gulp-nuget-restore package; the build works again if I manually overwrite it with a newer version.

So, I'm now trying to get the Gulp script to download the latest version of nuget.exe and use that for the package restore (this time by means of the [gulp-nuget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nuget) NPM package). Strangely, this works perfectly on my machine but fails on the TeamCity build server.

Here is the relevant part of my `gulpfile.js`:

```
const gulp = require("gulp"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    nuget = require("gulp-nuget"),
    download = require("gulp-download-stream");

const nugetExePath = "./nuget.exe";

gulp.task("download-nuget", done => {
    if (fs.existsSync(nugetExePath)) {
        return done();
    }

    return download(
        {
            file: "nuget.exe",
            url: "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe"
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("nuget-restore",
    ["download-nuget"],
    () => gulp.src("./mysolution.sln")
        .pipe(nuget.restore({
            nuget: nugetExePath,
            source: "http://our-internal-proget-server/nuget/Default/"
        })));
```

And the TeamCity build log:

```
[17:14:41][Step 2/2] Executing D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd via wrapping shell script
[17:14:41][Step 2/2] Starting: cmd /c D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd --no-color --teamcity.properties.all=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\temp\agentTmp\teamcity9135120293826835528.json     --teamcity.properties=D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\temp\agentTmp\teamcity7511878459063399775.json --configuration Release --enableteamcity --buildnumber 1299
[17:14:41][Step 2/2] in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65
[17:14:44][Step 2/2] [17:14:44] Using gulpfile D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\gulpfile.js
[17:14:44][Step 2/2] [17:14:44] Starting 'clean'...
[17:14:44][Step 2/2] [17:14:44] Starting 'set-build-number'...
[17:14:44][Step 2/2] [17:14:44] Starting 'download-nuget'...
[17:14:44][Step 2/2] [17:14:44] Downloading https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe...
[17:14:44][Step 2/2] [17:14:44] Finished 'clean' after 117 ms
[17:14:45][Step 2/2] [17:14:45] Updating assembly info file 'D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\SharedAssemblyInfo.cs'...
[17:14:45][Step 2/2] [17:14:45]     Setting attribute 'AssemblyVersion' to '1.0.*.1299'.
[17:14:45][Step 2/2] [17:14:45]     Setting attribute 'AssemblyVersion' to '1.3.9.1299'.
[17:14:45][Step 2/2] [17:14:45]     Setting attribute 'AssemblyFileVersion' to '1.3.9.1299'.
[17:14:46][Step 2/2] [17:14:46] Finished 'set-build-number' after 1.67 s
[17:14:48][Step 2/2] [17:14:48] Downloaded https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe after 3.98 s
[17:14:48][Step 2/2] [17:14:48] Finished 'download-nuget' after 4.01 s
[17:14:48][Step 2/2] [17:14:48] Starting 'nuget-restore'...
[17:14:48][Step 2/2] [17:14:48] 'nuget-restore' errored after 5.17 ms
[17:14:48][Step 2/2] [17:14:48] Error: spawnSync ./nuget.exe EBUSY
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at spawnSync (child_process.js:461:20)
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at execFileSync (child_process.js:498:13)
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at Gulp.gulp.task (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\gulpfile.js:109:9)
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at module.exports (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:279:18
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at finish (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
[17:14:48][Step 2/2]     at D:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\88991897ccf08f65\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4
[17:14:48][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
```

Does the "Error: spawnSync ./nuget.exe EBUSY" imply that something still has a lock on the `nuget.exe` file, even though the download has supposedly finished?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions about how to begin troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a horrible hack, but the error goes away if I introduce a 1-second time delay after finishing the download of nuget.exe:

```
const wait = require("gulp-wait");

gulp.task("download-nuget", done => {
    if (fs.existsSync(nugetExePath)) {
        return done();
    }

    return download(
        {
            file: "nuget.exe",
            url: "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe"
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
        .pipe(wait(1000)); // Workaround for EBUSY error on TeamCity server.
});
```